# How can I get only projects from the solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, envdte

I get a list of projects using following:

```
var solution = (IVsSolution)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsSolution));
```

Refer following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705089/how-to-get-list-of-projects-in-current-visual-studio-solution) for more details.

But it gives me each and every item in the solution like Directories, projects, etc.
I require only projects.

How can I get only projects from the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried and got the expected results.
There may be other better solution but this actually works for me.

```
var projects = CommonMethods.GetProjects(solution).Where(item => item.FullName != string.Empty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sry I'm just begining with programming so it could be that my solving way is really not the best but i faced the same problem short time ago.

To solve this problem I parsed all items of the solution in a list and later i just checked if the relativ path of the items has the suffix '.csproj' or any other kind of project i need and wrote them into a new list maybe this could help you to?