# How to bind solution with visual studio package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I am trying to create a visual studio package. I have tried to bind solution to package but it selects the first solution open. How can I bind solution to my package.

Comment: Please check following links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705089/how-to-get-list-of-projects-in-current-visual-studio-solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802945/how-can-i-get-only-projects-from-the-solution